# Not able to add external tester on testflight . How to enable testing?

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, itunes

It showing Waiting for Beta App Review.
Not Available for Testing

**How to make enable testing for external tester?**

Comment: IIRC, you can only add external testers once your app is reviewed and approved by Apple (similar to publishing to the store). Internal testers, on the other hand, you can add at any time - but there's a catch; they must be members of your organization (and if you have a **personal** developer account, it is not possible to add extra members).